# Extend UILabel to remove ascender?

Tags: swift, uilabel

In Interface Builder, I'd like to be able to align UILabels by the Cap Height. There's no way to do that in IB, so I thought I might extend UILabel so that the frame starts where Cap Height does (reduce the height of frame by ascender-cap height, then render the text higher by that difference). I'm not quite sure how to get the text to draw at the new origin though. How can I subclass UILabel so that the frame hugs the Cap Height?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to subclass `UILabel` and override `alignmentRectInsets`:

```
@IBDesignable
class CapHeightAligningLabel: UILabel {

    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: font.ascender - font.capHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

}
```

I made three labels: one `UILabel` and two `CapHeightAligningLabel`s. I aligned the tops of all three. I also made a 1-point height blue view whose bottom is aligned to the top of one of the custom labels, so it draws what auto layout thinks is the top of the label. Here's the result:

[image: layout result]

As you can see, the custom labels are aligned at their cap heights, and the normal label's true top is also aligned to the cap height of both custom labels.

Note that with this solution, there's no longer a way to align anything to the true top of one of these custom label.

Also note that I didn't test this with any special text effects like letterpress, shadow, or underlining. Those might throw off my inset calculation.

If you need different approach (because you also need to align to the true top of the label), then maybe overriding `viewForLastBaselineLayout` would work better. That should let you change where auto layout thinks the baseline of the label is. Move the baseline to the cap height, and then constrain to the baseline. Then you can constrain to both the cap height and the true top, but of course you won't be able to constrain to the true baseline. I haven't tried this solution.

Comment: In Swift 3 alignmentRectInsets is no longer a func, its now a property. However its a get only property, so is this solution still possible? (I'm trying to override the property but getting problems due to it being get only)